# Dart list of exactly two types

Tags: dart, static-typing

Is it possible in Dart to have a list of exactly two types like you can in TypeScript? For example, something like this would compile:

```
List<int|String> foo = [
    1,2,3,4,'baz'
];
```

while this wouldn't:

```
List<int|String> foo = [
    1,2,false,4,'baz',[],3.0
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The Dart type system does not contain general union types. It cannot express "must be `int` or `String`" in the type system

The two available exceptions are:

- Something or `Null` (nullable types, like `int?`).
- Something or a `Future` of the same thing (`FutureOr`).

Those two union types are known by the type system
For all other combinations, all you can do is to pick a type which is a super-type of both the types. In this situation, the nearest common supertype is `Object`. The type system won't prevent you from putting booleans or lists into that.

Comment: And using Object is preferable to using dynamic?

Comment: Depends. Using `dynamic` is the traditional way to say "something fishy is going on here", but it also comes with the risk of hiding errors. If you accidentally assign the `dynamic`-typed value to `int` without first checking whether it's an `int` or a `String`, then you won't get any warnings. With `Object?` you would. Using `Object` here is really just because it's the smallest supertype of both `int` and `String`. It accepts every `int` and `String`, but not `null`.